# Using grep -v on multiple arguments

Tags: grep, solaris

Is there a simpler way to do this? 
`grep -v foo file | grep -v bar`

There're probably very elegant ways to do it with egrep, but how to go with plain old grep?

EDIT: `grep -v 'foo\|bar' file` seems to work only with GNU grep. I'm on Solaris. Any solution for that?

Comment: Strange question because in the first example you are doing AND match, and in the second you are doing OR match. The outcome will be the same only in very specific conditions.

Comment: No not really. In the second example, the `-v` flag is a negation. `not(A or B) == not(A) and not(B)`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can have multiple tests in a single `grep` command by passing each expression with a `-e` argument instead of as the first non-option argument as you normally see:

```
$ grep -v -e foo -e bar file
```

That says the same thing your command does: print lines from `file` that contain neither "foo" nor "bar".

Keep in mind that removing `-v` completely inverts this; it changes the logical operation, too! You get all lines that contain "foo" *or* "bar".

Answer (score 22):

`grep -Ev 'word1|word2'` should work just fine

Comment: As an alternative you can use egrep and drop the backslash for the pipe character: `egrep -v 'word1|word2`

Comment: Turns out this does not work with the Solaris grep. I installed the GNU grep and worked perfectly. I'm going to edit my question to make it Solaris specific.

Comment: @rahmu `\|` is a GNU grep extension, but you can achieve the same thing in a portable way with `-E` and the `|` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use curly braces for parameter expansion:

```
grep -v -e{foo,bar}
```

which effectively is the same as:

```
grep -v -e foo -e bar
```

(I don't have enough reputation points to add this as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 11.4, if you set your `PATH` variable correctly to pick up the command line tools that are slightly more usable than the default set, then you would be able to use

```bsh
grep -E -v 'foo|bar' file
```

You get this more capable `grep` as your default `grep` if you set your `PATH` like so:

```
PATH=$(/usr/xpg6/bin/getconf PATH):$PATH
```

This would add the following paths to the front of your existing `PATH` variable's value, on a default Solaris 11.4 system:

```
/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/developerstudio12.5/bin:/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin
```

See also `man standards` on a Solaris system.